# Meaning of "being" in "being necessary to the security of a free state"

Tags: grammar, meaning, word-meaning

> Amendmentⅱ
>
> A well-regulated militia, **being** necessary to the security of a free state, the right of the people to keep and bear arms, shall not be infringed.

Is it participial construction? Was "being" in this context originally "*As* it(militia) is..."?

Or does it a have different meaning? What's the grammatical role of "being" here and how should I interpret the sentence?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that comma usage was a little different when that was written. The modern version would omit the comma after "militia" and the one after "arms":

> *A well-regulated militia being necessary to the security of a free state*, the right of the people to keep and bear arms shall not be infringed.

The italicized part is an "absolute phrase/construction", which is independent of the structure of the rest of the sentence. In this example, it establishes a reason for the clause that follows it.

[Wikipedia "absolute construction"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction)
There are a few other examples at that link of an absolute construction in English; they all use participial verb forms.

The sentence could be rephrased like this:

> The right of the people to keep and bear arms shall not be infringed because a well-regulated militia is necessary to the security of a free state.

The verb "to be", which appears as "is" in this rephrasing, occurs in participle form "being" in the absolute construction.